# Как правильно подключить bootstrap4 в elecrone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, npm, electron

Столкнулся с проблемой подключение js библиотек, вот как и я подключаю:

```
<script>
  require('jquery')
  require('popper.js')
  require('bootstrap-beta')
</script>
```

При сборке проекта в десктоп приложение вылетает такая ошибка:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/misha/summary/node_modules/bootstrap-beta/dist/js/bootstrap.js:3920:6)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/misha/summary/node_modules/bootstrap-beta/dist/js/bootstrap.js:3922:3)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at file:///home/misha/summary/main.html:109:5
```

Есть ли идеи как обойти это? заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала установить библиотеки:

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install popper.js --save
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta --save
```

И чтобы подключить bootstrap:

```
<script>
  require('jquery');                            // подключение jquery
  window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery')  // для работы $
  window.Popper = require('popper.js')          // для работы bootstrap
  require('bootstrap')
</script>
```